# How can I implement relative urls (with #) in crafter 3?

Tags: crafter-cms

I am using [viewerjs](http://viewerjs.org/instructions/) library in crafter 3

The thing is the library uses a relative url in order to work just like this:

```
<a href="http://example.org/ViewerJS/#../path/to/filename.ext">
```

the problem is when I do the same in crafter I get this error:

Caused by: org.craftercms.core.exception.StoreException: Unable to find content: ../data/repos/sites/viewerv2/sandbox/static-assets/viewerJS is not a file

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: fixed: I found the solution:  /viewerJS/index.html#../path/to/the/file.ext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed:

```
/viewerJS/index.html#../path/to/the/file.ext
```

instead of just write #.. we need to add the index.html as well, and the path to the file